# Are there any way to watch video in portrait mode?

Tags: video, mediaplayer, orientation

I have tried some apps but none have worked so far. Any suggestions?

Comment: For videos shot in portrait, or those shot in landscape?

Comment: for any video. If you have used Android, pretty much any videoplayer let you play video in portrait or landscape.

Comment: Have you tried VLC by changing the settings ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[VLC for Windows Phone](http://www.windowsphone.com/s?appId=44fa83f7-a98d-4647-b9d4-c35ed729d0c9) ought to do the trick for you. The default video player in Windows 10 Mobile also lets you do this.

Comment: Last time I tried VLC it didn't have that feature. Thank you :)